# Event listener for window.fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Is there a way to globally monitor all `window.fetch` requests? I know it works with Promises, but I need to get notified whenever any of such requests is done (fail/success) and I have no access to the functions which invoke these or which are success/fail handlers.

So basically I'm looking for something like:

```
window.addEventListener('fetch', ev => {
  if (ev.type == 'FetchSuccess') {
    // process ev.response
  }
});
```

Comment: Note: future readers may be interested in looking into [hooking into the fetch request system via a service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can overwrite the fetch function the following way:

```
var oldFetch = fetch;  // must be on the global scope
fetch = function(url, options) {
    var promise = oldFetch(url, options);
    // Do something with the promise
    return promise;
}
```

This way you can get control over the returned promises while it maintains it's usage.

Comment: Yup.. looks like this will do. I hoped for a more unintrusive way where I wouldn't fiddle around with the natives.